# overflow auto div overlap Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]

I want datetime widget show properly. i use z-index in bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget. but it is not work. the problem is overflow:auto; in my panel-body.

find my code here:`<https://jsfiddle.net/danishwebindia/0Ltv25o8/2166/>`

Comment: find my code from above link

Comment: its working properly on the shared fiddle

Comment: i want datetimepicker widget popup out of the container but container should be overflow auto.

Answer (score 0):

where you are using datepicker function in jquery try to put

```
 orientation: 'auto bottom'
```

but then also it will show problem as your outer div is fixed you need to increase the size of that